# Start Alarm on Android without having the application running

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

My idea is to set an alarm for a specific date in my application, but I want to be able to have the alarm ringing at the set date, even if my application isn't running at all.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start a service when the device is booted - that service should take care about the alarming when the time has come.

To make your service be started at boot time you need the following things in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

in the `<manifest>` tag

```
<receiver android:name="com.yourpackage.AlarmingBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

in your `<application>` tag

Additionally you need your `AlarmingBroadcastReceiver`, should look something like that to start the service:

```
public class AlarmingBroadcastreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmingService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

whereas `AlarmingService.class` is the class name of your service that finally takes care about the alarming stuff

Comment: AlarmingBroadcastreceiver will start the serivece AlarmingService.class, but how do I from an Activity tell the AlarmingBroadcastreceiver to start the service?

Comment: From an activity you don't need to go via AlarmingBroadcastreceiver - you can start the service from the Activity directly by an Ìntent`and `startService()` - similar to the code in the BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Okay, let's say i start AlarmService.class from MyActivity.

Comment: When will onReceive method be executed!?

Comment: that's just relevant for that the service is started automatically at boot time

Comment: I've made the onReceive method to run after 60 seconds say. But it doesn't while my application is not running, how come?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a onBoot BroadCast Receiver so when the device is started your application will get control to set up alarms.